# Textbox width in razor

Tags: razor

how to adjust textbox width in razor code? My code below does not work:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PDFLink, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control",style="width:300px" } })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class with the Width you want and use that class for all text box you want. Something like below.

`.setWith {
    max-width: 350px;
}`

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PDFLink, "", new { @class = "form-control setWith", placeholder = "If You want Any.." })`

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it works.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PDFLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@style="100% !important; min-width:600px;" } })
```